How do you play half/fully diminished chords on the piano?
I am trying to play the half/fully diminished chords on the piano but it is very difficult, especially so for Bb, Eb, Ab, Db, Gb.
Is there a tip on how to play those chords?

Are you saying the fingering is difficult? Or figuring out which notes to play? Or something else? Are you able to play other types of 7th chords?

Each and every one of those ten chords will have to use thumb on the root note (r.h.)- which inevitably is a black key. Although it's generally accepted that we try not to do this, here, with r.h., it's unavoidable.
You'll end up with thumb on the edge of that key closest to you, only needs to be played on the very edge, leaving three other fingers (your choice) which will fall naturally on the remaining three keys. Often quite far into the keyboard. That's fine.
To achieve this, move your right elbow closer to your body, giving the thumb a little more reach.
If it's your l.h. that's causing the problem, do the exact opposite!

Why would you be obliged to play the root note with the right hand, and why would it have to be played by the thumb?!

@user1079505 - how else, unless one's stretch is quite wide?

You can 1) play the root with the left hand, 2) play an inversion

@user1079505 - there's always options like this - answer?

The piano keys to press for the chords (in root position)
For fully diminished seventh chords, the piano keys to press are:

Bb°7: Bb Db E G (Conventional note names: Bb Db Fb Abb)
Eb°7: Eb Gb A C (Conventional: Eb Gb Bbb Dbb)
Ab°7: Ab B  D F (Conventional: Ab Cb Ebb Gbb)
Db°7: Db E  G Bb (Conventional: Db Fb Abb Cbb)
Gb°7: Gb A  C Eb (Conventional: Gb Bbb Dbb Fbb)

For half diminished seventh chords, the highest note is increased by a semitone, so the piano keys to press are:

Bbm7(♭5): Bb Db E Ab (Conventional note names: Bb Db Fb Ab)
Ebm7(♭5): Eb Gb A Db (Conventional: Eb Gb Bbb Db)
Abm7(♭5): Ab B  D Gb (Conventional: Ab Cb Ebb Gb)
Dbm7(♭5): Db E  G B (Conventional: Db Fb Abb Cb)
Gbm7(♭5): Gb A  C E (Conventional: Gb Bbb Dbb Fb)

Notes:

See this interactive tool for the notes for the 3 common variations of a seventh chord in any key, where you can also see

the logic behind constructing those chords a) in terms of intervals between notes, or b) in terms of scale degrees
the standard notation of the chords (in terms of scale degrees) thus using loads of accidentals


Since this is an answer to a how to play question, I purposefully simplify the note names to piano key names (the enharmonic equivalent) so it's easier to find on the keyboard, rather than being a theoretical stickler to the conventional note names as they appear on the sheet.  I'm mainly a performer not a theoretician, so I provide names that are helpful to a performer.
At any rate, I also provide the conventional note names next to it in parenthesis, because it IS helpful to figure out the notes in terms of scale degrees since you can consistently skip a letter for the next higher note and that the highest note is always the 7th scale degree.

How to play 4-note chords on the piano
I notice that the root of all your chords are black keys, which you play with the thumb (if you are playing with your RH).  You simply move your whole hand forward in a natural position so your thumb is comfortably on the edge of the black key and use the closest fingers for the remaining notes, curving them as needed.  In several cases, your little finger will end up on a black key as well, which is okay.  The most important is that the finger tips are touching the keys in a natural, relaxed, and stable place while the wrist staying straight, so you can hit the chords with minimal vertical wrist movement that will bring down together all your (already curved) fingers at the same time.
Now there are many short YouTube videos on hand postures for playing chords on the piano.  One example is this 5 minute video from Piano Roadmap which has an example on how to practice playing a 4-note chords by first playing the outer 2 notes (with thumb and little finger) and then adding the 2 inner notes.  Although the example is for the left hand using as example a F minor 1st inversion chord (Ab C F Ab), the same principle applies to play the half/fully diminished chords above.
